# PopupWindow + full screen => show notification-bar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notification-bar, android-popupwindow

### Background

I'm making an activity that has 2 fragments.

the second fragment shows a full screen image, which also hides the status bar (AKA notification bar) using:

```
    final View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        uiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

### The problem

I'm trying to add a sharing dialog of the currently shown image, but no matter which method I try to do it, it always shows the status bar, making things "jumpy".

### What I've tried

The normal way to open the sharing dialog didn't work (I mean, it worked, but it showed the status bar) :

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"some text");
```

So I had to create my own popup.

First I wanted to show some sort of progressDialog, but it also caused the status bar to show, so I removed it.

Then I wanted to show a list of the items, so I used ListPopupWindow (anchored to the view the user is clicking) , but it also showed the status bar. Another thing I tried is to use the normal PopupWindow and set a listView inside of it, but it also didn't help.

Another thing that I tried is to change the window of the popupWindow to have the same settings as the fragment's activity, but it also didn't help.

I even tried to set a smaller height for the popup, but it didn't help.

### The question

How can I use a PopupWindow (or the normal sharing dialog) so that the status bar will remain in the same state as it did before showing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I've found the perfect combination. I used the normal sharing intent, and set the flags of the window as needed.

for hiding/showing the status bar correctly :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void setStatuBarVisibility(final boolean visible) {
    if (visible) {
        // if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        final View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
        // a no animation version of: getActivity().getActionBar().show();
        ViewUtil.getActionBarView(getActivity()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // hide status bar (if possible) and the action bar, and dim navigation buttons:
        final View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE;
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            uiOptions |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        // if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        // a no animation version of: getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
        ViewUtil.getActionBarView(getActivity()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ViewUtil.hideSoftKeyboardFromFocusedView(getActivity());
    }
}

public static View getActionBarView(final FragmentActivity activity) {
    final Window window = activity.getWindow();
    final View v = window.getDecorView();
    final int resId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_container", "id", "android");
    return v.findViewById(resId);
}

public static void hideSoftKeyboardFromFocusedView(final Context context, final View view) {
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

it also avoids the jumpy behavior when going to/from the fragment, and when showing the sharing dialog.